# SQL:How can I ignore NULL or 0 values in database and return rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, null

I have a MySQL table in which some values are NULL or 0 (None) for some rows and I would like to select them and return them to my PHP code along with non-NULL or non-zero rows.

Therefore, I would like to return all existing rows regardless of them being null or zero. I would like to show the digit 0 to the user where 0 (None) or NULL is found in the database instead of omitting rows where the aforementioned values are found since not all columns are 0 or NULL.

This is the query I'm currently using;

```
SELECT ops_files.file_id, ops_files.file_name, ops_files.description, ops_file_cats.file_cat, 
    ops_file_status.status, ops_files.date_of_instructions, bd_orgs.name org1, bd_orgs2.name org2, bd_clients.name client1, bd_clients2.name client2,
    bd_clients3.name client3, bd_clients4.name client4, bd_clients5.name client5, ops_int_parties.name int_party1, ops_int_parties2.name int_party2 FROM ops_files 
    INNER JOIN ops_file_cats ON ops_files.file_cat = ops_file_cats.cat_id 
    INNER JOIN ops_file_status ON ops_files.file_status = ops_file_status.status_id 
    INNER JOIN bd_orgs ON ops_files.org1 = bd_orgs.org_id
    INNER JOIN bd_orgs bd_orgs2 ON ops_files.org2 = bd_orgs2.org_id
    INNER JOIN bd_clients ON ops_files.contact_person1 = bd_clients.client_id
    INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients2 ON ops_files.contact_person2 = bd_clients2.client_id
    INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients3 ON ops_files.contact_person3 = bd_clients3.client_id
    INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients4 ON ops_files.contact_person4 = bd_clients4.client_id  
    INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients5 ON ops_files.contact_person5 = bd_clients5.client_id
    INNER JOIN ops_int_parties ON ops_files.int_party1 = ops_int_parties.id
    INNER JOIN ops_int_parties ops_int_parties2 ON ops_files.int_party2 = ops_int_parties2.id ORDER BY file_id ASC
```

And here's a snapshot of one of the MySQL tables.

**Note**: I've deliberately erased some values in the attached image.

[image: database image of one of the tables]

**UPDATE**:

I'm trying to implement what @scaisEdge suggested but I am getting an error every time I try to use IFNULL with an alias. How do I correctly implement IFNULL for the columns `bd_orgs.name org1` all the way to `ops_int_parties2.name int_party2` in the query below? Been scratching my head for hours to no avail.

```
SELECT ops_files.file_id, 
                    IFNULL(ops_files.file_name,0) file_name,
                    IFNULL(ops_files.description,0) description,
                    IFNULL(ops_file_cats.file_cat,0) file_cat, 
                    IFNULL(ops_file_status.status,0) status,
                    IFNULL(ops_files.date_of_instructions,0) date_of_instructions,
                    bd_orgs.name org1,
                    bd_orgs2.name org2,
                    bd_clients.name client1, 
                    bd_clients2.name client2,
                    bd_clients3.name client3,
                    bd_clients4.name client4,
                    bd_clients5.name client5,
                    ops_int_parties.name int_party1,
                    ops_int_parties2.name int_party2
                    
                    FROM ops_files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want NULL value return 0  you could try using `ifnull(your_column, 0)`

```
SELECT ops_files.file_id

, ifnull(ops_files.file_name,0) file_name
, ifnull(ops_files.description,0) description 
......
......

FROM ops_files 
INNER JOIN ops_file_cats ON ops_files.file_cat = ops_file_cats.cat_id 
INNER JOIN ops_file_status ON ops_files.file_status = ops_file_status.status_id 
INNER JOIN bd_orgs ON ops_files.org1 = bd_orgs.org_id
INNER JOIN bd_orgs bd_orgs2 ON ops_files.org2 = bd_orgs2.org_id
INNER JOIN bd_clients ON ops_files.contact_person1 = bd_clients.client_id
INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients2 ON ops_files.contact_person2 = bd_clients2.client_id
INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients3 ON ops_files.contact_person3 = bd_clients3.client_id
INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients4 ON ops_files.contact_person4 = bd_clients4.client_id  
INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients5 ON ops_files.contact_person5 = bd_clients5.client_id
INNER JOIN ops_int_parties ON ops_files.int_party1 = ops_int_parties.id
INNER JOIN ops_int_parties ops_int_parties2 ON ops_files.int_party2 = ops_int_parties2.id ORDER BY file_id ASC
```

and if the column are involved  in join use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT ops_files.file_id

, ifnull(ops_files.file_name,0) file_name
, ifnull(ops_files.description,0) description 
......
......

FROM ops_files 
LEFT  JOIN ops_file_cats ON ops_files.file_cat = ops_file_cats.cat_id 
LEFT  JOIN ops_file_status ON ops_files.file_status = ops_file_status.status_id 
LEFT  JOIN bd_orgs ON ops_files.org1 = bd_orgs.org_id
LEFT  JOIN bd_orgs bd_orgs2 ON ops_files.org2 = bd_orgs2.org_id
LEFT  JOIN bd_clients ON ops_files.contact_person1 = bd_clients.client_id
LEFT  JOIN bd_clients bd_clients2 ON ops_files.contact_person2 = bd_clients2.client_id
LEFT  JOIN bd_clients bd_clients3 ON ops_files.contact_person3 = bd_clients3.client_id
LEFT  JOIN bd_clients bd_clients4 ON ops_files.contact_person4 = bd_clients4.client_id  
LEFT  JOIN bd_clients bd_clients5 ON ops_files.contact_person5 = bd_clients5.client_id
LEFT  JOIN ops_int_parties ON ops_files.int_party1 = ops_int_parties.id
LEFT  JOIN ops_int_parties ops_int_parties2 ON ops_files.int_party2 = ops_int_parties2.id ORDER BY file_id ASC
```

In you query you refer  the select clause to columns contained in tables ops_file_cats, ops_file_status, bd_orgs, bd_orgs2 and so on .....
buut you have not joined  these tables try add the join properly

```
SELECT ops_files.file_id, 
IFNULL(ops_files.file_name,0) file_name,
IFNULL(ops_files.description,0) description,
IFNULL(ops_file_cats.file_cat,0) file_cat, 
IFNULL(ops_file_status.status,0) status,
IFNULL(ops_files.date_of_instructions,0) date_of_instructions,
bd_orgs.name org1,
bd_orgs2.name org2,
bd_clients.name client1, 
bd_clients2.name client2,
bd_clients3.name client3,
bd_clients4.name client4,
bd_clients5.name client5,
ops_int_parties.name int_party1,
ops_int_parties2.name int_party2
FROM ops_files 
INNER JOIN ops_file_cats ON ops_files.file_cat = ops_file_cats.cat_id 
INNER JOIN ops_file_status ON ops_files.file_status = ops_file_status.status_id 
INNER JOIN bd_orgs ON ops_files.org1 = bd_orgs.org_id
INNER JOIN bd_orgs bd_orgs2 ON ops_files.org2 = bd_orgs2.org_id
INNER JOIN bd_clients ON ops_files.contact_person1 = bd_clients.client_id
INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients2 ON ops_files.contact_person2 = bd_clients2.client_id
INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients3 ON ops_files.contact_person3 = bd_clients3.client_id
INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients4 ON ops_files.contact_person4 = bd_clients4.client_id  
INNER JOIN bd_clients bd_clients5 ON ops_files.contact_person5 = bd_clients5.client_id
INNER JOIN ops_int_parties ON ops_files.int_party1 = ops_int_parties.id
INNER JOIN ops_int_parties ops_int_parties2 ON ops_files.int_party2 = ops_int_parties2.id ORDER BY file_id ASC
```

or use left join you nedd  partial match too

```
SELECT ops_files.file_id, 
IFNULL(ops_files.file_name,0) file_name,
IFNULL(ops_files.description,0) description,
IFNULL(ops_file_cats.file_cat,0) file_cat, 
IFNULL(ops_file_status.status,0) status,
IFNULL(ops_files.date_of_instructions,0) date_of_instructions,
bd_orgs.name org1,
bd_orgs2.name org2,
bd_clients.name client1, 
bd_clients2.name client2,
bd_clients3.name client3,
bd_clients4.name client4,
bd_clients5.name client5,
ops_int_parties.name int_party1,
ops_int_parties2.name int_party2
FROM ops_files 
LEFT JOIN ops_file_cats ON ops_files.file_cat = ops_file_cats.cat_id 
LEFT JOIN ops_file_status ON ops_files.file_status = ops_file_status.status_id 
LEFT JOIN bd_orgs ON ops_files.org1 = bd_orgs.org_id
LEFT JOIN bd_orgs bd_orgs2 ON ops_files.org2 = bd_orgs2.org_id
LEFT JOIN bd_clients ON ops_files.contact_person1 = bd_clients.client_id
LEFT JOIN bd_clients bd_clients2 ON ops_files.contact_person2 = bd_clients2.client_id
LEFT JOIN bd_clients bd_clients3 ON ops_files.contact_person3 = bd_clients3.client_id
LEFT JOIN bd_clients bd_clients4 ON ops_files.contact_person4 = bd_clients4.client_id  
LEFT JOIN bd_clients bd_clients5 ON ops_files.contact_person5 = bd_clients5.client_id
LEFT JOIN ops_int_parties ON ops_files.int_party1 = ops_int_parties.id
LEFT JOIN ops_int_parties ops_int_parties2 ON ops_files.int_party2 = ops_int_parties2.id ORDER BY file_id ASC
```

and last  in the join clause if you have remaapped  column name with alias you must repeat a valid code

```
INNER JOIN ops_file_cats ON ifnull(ops_files.file_cat,0) = ifnull(ops_file_cats.cat_id ,0)
```

Comment: I appreciate your timely response. However, I am getting the error **Unrecognized keyword** in every statement after the fourth `IFNULL` in phpMyAdmin. There are no syntactic errors - I've checked each and every line very meticulously. What could be the problem?

Comment: update your question and add  your actual code ..  so i can inspect

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @calibra  answer updated ..  you must join all the table you use in select clause  the fourth ifnull  is related to  ops_file_cats table  but have not a join for this table  .. and so on for others table/columns

Comment: I have the right sql query and I have joined all the tables correctly... it's only that I had left out the second part of the query (containing INNER JOINs) out of the update. My second question was on how to use IFNULL with alias on the columns bd_orgs.name org1 all the way to ops_int_parties2.name int_party2 in the SELECT clause.

Comment: You can't  column alias in where or join  (select clause)  ..  you must repeat the code  .. the select clause is evaluated by db engine after the from  and where clause  .so the alias is not available for these clause  ..anyway answer upated  for the join condition with remapped  column name